# How do I filter duplicates in Entity Framework minimize performance loss?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I make the performance better of the code below?

I'm loading the carItems from an external webservice in a list. 
carItem is checked whether it exists in EF. 
If carItem is new, then it's mapped to carsCol and added to the database. What are some easy ways to improve the performance of this using code?

```
        carItems = carItems.Where(x => x.Name == "Tesla");

        // Filter existing cars
        List<Car> carsCol = new List<Car>();
        foreach (var item in carItems)
        {
            if (GetById(item.Id) == null)
            {
                carsCol.Add(item);
            }
        }

        Entities.AddRange(carsCol);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, you can try to find out which ids already exist in the database by making a single query before the foreach.

```
var newCarItemIds = carItems.Select(x => x.Id);
var alreadyExistentCarItemIds = Entities.CarItems.Where(x => newCarItemIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x=>x.Id);

foreach(var item in carItems)
{
    if(!alreadyExistentCarItemIds.Contains(x))
    {
        carsCol.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed more efficient. Would you place this code in the Controller or a customized method in the the Repository?

Comment: I do not know exactly the architecture of your project but I can give you my opinion on it. I'll try to keep Controllers as clean as possible so I would probably move this logic in the Business Logic Layer. If you think this is the correct answer for your question, can you mark the answer as "correct"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct Linq functions: [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)
You must to implement IEquatable interface

Comment: In what way would this be more efficient? Does this mean that I need to retrieve all entities (>10.000) from EF and then distinct against (500)?

Comment: You read entities from wcf, than filter distict elements with List and finally check on EF.

Comment: `Distinct` *eliminates* duplicates. It doesn't *discover* duplicates. Also `IEquatable` doesn't play a role in LINQ to a SQL backend.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this. You can do a `left outter join` with the cars that you get from your API and the existing one. Than you get the new cars that will be added.

```
var newCars = (from c in carItems 
          join e in Entities.CarItems on c.Id equals e.Id into g
          from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { c, IsNew = x == null }).Where(x = x.IsNew).ToList()
```

With that you do only one access to the database. Also when working with `IEnumerable` is always good to convert it to either a list or array, that way each time that you iterates through that object you don't run a query in your database.